# api design - How to design public POST api to prevent spam request

Tags: node.js, database, api, api-design

I am developing a public website
One of the page is to let people submit opinions.
They need to enter email, phone, message ,etc, in order to submit the opinion form.

This means I need to make an api for people, so that after they press the submit button, the POST request will be sent.

But some people might abuse this function(e.g. create bot to send massive amount of POST request).

Since the frontend design is already finished and no recapcha is used in frontend, I was thinking if there are backend ways to do it.

Is there any ways/best practice to prevent this kind of things?
I am using node.js(aws lambda) for my api function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if there is still a way to implement captchas, use package "svg-captcha". If you only want to deal with the backend, refer to this [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent): `req.headers['user-agent'];`, so you can track down those who abuse the requests and limit their access for a while.